# If more than N answers are submitted within T seconds, how can we promote obscured good answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answer-quality, fastest-gun

A good indicator of a trivial question is that many answers are submitted in a short space of time.  I suggest that we consider both the quality of the question, and the quality of answers that result.

Question quality:  The question may be acceptable, and SO has mechanisms for reviewing questions.  However, it might be worth giving questions that fit these conditions greater scrutiny.

Answer quality:  If a flurry of answers is received, then typically one of the following appears to be true.

1. The submitted answers are correct, but of little value because the question is trivial.
2. The answers vary in quality, but their abundance leaves the truly good answers buried beneath the supply of mediocre responses.

There seems to be great competition to answer these specific kinds of questions.  Would it not be better to decrease the incentive to answer them?  Perhaps neither the questions, nor the answers should accrue any points.  In this way, the only incentive for submitting additional answers, or modifying a submitted answer, is to improve the quality of the knowledge captured on SO.

There may be other alternatives.  How can we promote writing a smaller number of quality answers for questions that draw too many responses?

Comment: What you're suggesting is basically to kick in community wiki much sooner if the answers come in quick succession. I'm not voting for the feature request, but I find the discussion useful.

Comment: Classic example: "I want to use regexp to match a number with 3 digits, a slash (`-`)  and again 3 numbers". 1 Min after this question has been posted several answers are written. all with the same result of `(\d{3})-(\d{3})`.

Comment: What about an automatic downvote (or just reputation loss) for answers that are exact duplicates of some other?

Comment: @JanDvorak Auto-downvoting could work, but I think exact duplicates only occur abundantly in the most extreme cases.

Comment: @JanDvorak These bikeshed questions tend to be upvote magnets.  A single downvote isn't enough to discourage answering them.

Comment: @Servy I think the correct answer is to negate any rep gain (but not rep loss?) from a closed question as if the question was deleted. Maybe CW-fy on second close?

Comment: [An other example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042393/how-can-a-b-b-a-a-b-be-true), a duplicate was last week in the "hot questions", and this question managed it into the hot questions too.

Comment: @JanDvorak auto-downvoting wouldn't be good. It would be a punishment for something people couldn't avoid. If someone hits submit before he have opportunity to see an answers few seconds older, and he started to write when there was no answers yet, punishing him with downvote / rep loss seems unfair. If anything, putting question on auto-on-hold if it has more than 3 answers in first minutes might work - as a punishment for probable lack of own research, if it's *that* simple.

Comment: @molot but then you have to hide/lock/votelock/replock/autodownvote said first three answers until the question is reopened. Otherwise the entire process becomes a race to be one of the three that have the right to answer - knowing that no matter how crappy their answer^K placeholder is, it will get upvoted because the competition is so little. Or just implement close = replock to complement this.

Comment: @JanDvorak close = replock seems fine.

Answer (score 11):

Voting is everything.

If you don't like a question's quality, vote it down (and vote up the interesting, well-written ones that show background knowledge and research).  That's how we sort the good questions from the marginal ones.  People can still answer these questions, if they're on-topic, but voting them down sorts them to the bottom of the list, and leaves room for the good ones at the top.  (the actual sorting algorithm is a bit more complicated than this, of course).

I don't know what to tell you about the bikeshed votes or the sympathy upvotes (those folks don't understand how voting works, and changing people's behavior is difficult), other than to say that the questions that get Reddited are comparatively rare.

Comment: I do agree that voting is very important, but I don't think it's enough. Moreover, some people just [don't believe in this theory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053981/passing-a-value-into-a-form-field-using-javascript?noredirect=1#comment28161922_19053981) and enough of people just vote opposite the current score in all cases diminishing or reversing the value of downvotes.

Comment: Maybe SE can see fit to increase the weighting of downvotes on question sorting.

Comment: Which won't demotivate rep-hunters the least bit. I think the rep-hunters (and the associated diminishment in the value of reputation) are the biggest problem.

Comment: @JanDvorak: The problem as I see it is not about rep, it's about keeping the marginal questions away from the experts.  The rep farmers are, by and large, not the experts, and if you can keep the question lists for the experts fresh with good questions, that leaves the marginal questions for the enthusiasts to answer.  Let them earn the rep on those questions.

Comment: And if the experts want to do crystal-ball troubleshooting on the marginal questions, let them.  The only remaining factor is people getting lazy with their close votes and downvotes, and I have a proposal for that, which I am going to post shortly on Meta.

Comment: @JanDvorak: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198627/102937

Comment: Voting is everything when it is feasible to consider all available candidates, and the question warrants doing so. If there are too many answers, the first-few bias will render the votes meaningless.

Comment: Robert, I appreciate the ideals of your answer. I have posted two answers in the theme of the question -- to promote discussion.  I would appreciate any feedback you might have there as well.

Answer (score 2):

*Quality-first* approach:

A quality-first approach to this problem would start new questions in an *initially-ineligible* state with regards to the receiving of reputation gains (both for the question and the answers).  Under such a state, downvotes continue to count toward reputation loss.  However, a simple set of conditions that indicate a reasonable level of quality, the question may be converted into an *eligible* state.  Under this state reputation is awarded according to the normal rules.  Reputation is also awarded retro-actively.

This sounds a bit more complicated, but I think a reasonable set of simple conditions can be specified.  Most questions should only be in the *limbo* state for a brief period of perhaps 2 minutes.  Here are conditions that may perhaps work:

To become reputation-eligible, questions must satisfy *ALL* of the following:

1. The question is older than *R* seconds, but younger than *T* time. (Guide: *R = 90 seconds, T = 2 days*)
2. The question does not have a negative number of votes below threshold *M*. (Guide: *M = 1*)
3. Fewer than *N* answers were generated within the first *R* seconds. (Guide: *N = 5*)

To become reputation-eligible, questions must satisfy at least *ONE* of the following:

1. The variance of the top *K* non-negative voted answers is no less than threshold *Q*. (Guide: *K = 4, Q = 1*)
2. Fewer than *J* answers are generated within time *T*. (Guide: *J = 3*)

The first set of conditions ensure that low-value questions are not promoted.  The second set of conditions ensure that questions that produce a large number of close scoring answers are also not promoted.

Most reasonable questions will meet such criteria quickly, and become reputation-eligible.  Such a system could promote the value of the reputation system, while discouraging a flood of low quality submissions.  However, it is also requires more investigation work, and may also be controversial.

Comment: Would that not discourage people from adding new answers when 5 others have got it all wrong, posting gibberish in the first 30 seconds, while they are busy typing up a detailed response?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Quite possibly. However, many SO member are good citizens who are motivated to elevate the quality content. The entire community wiki mechanism is built upon that fact.

Answer (score 0):

*Reputation-first* approach:

A reputation-first approach to this problem would allow participants to gain reputation which could subsequently be removed for questions that meet the described criteria.

Jan Dvorak suggests that this could be handled by triggering Community Wiki conversion earlier.  Presently, the conversion happens after a questions generates [about 30 answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).  The conditions for CW-conversion could be extended to include a time-limited lower threshold, such as: *the question generated 5 answers within the first 90 seconds*.