# Another idea for close-vote queue rejuvenation: Show the number of items added today, not the total number

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

This is just one more idea for a way to rejuvenate people's interest in the SO CV queue - which, at the time of this writing, is at **84.7k** reviews needed.

Some people are working hard to try to drum up more interest in the queue - Robert has a great idea with the [proposed contest for close review queue posse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198627/proposed-contest-for-close-review-queue-posse). Still, it seems that the big number scares many people off.

[image]

What can we do about this? From what I can see, the problem stems primarily from the big number. So let's get rid of the big number! But we can't lie. Lying is bad.

So, I propose that we stop showing the total number of reviews needed all big and bold like that - let's just show the total number of reviews added today minus the number of reviews performed today:

[image]

<sup>Much better!</sup>

When the community is making *progress* on the queue, let's show that:

[image]

Basically what I'm getting at is some kind of a delta-reviews (delta-R) system - thereby making the big number seem a little less huge.

I'd even be in favor of showing both numbers simultaneously, though this would probably be bordering on too complicated:

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: I see this as functionally identical to the previous suggestion of just hiding the queue's current count entirely.  Can't find the question atm.

Comment: Is that a bad thing?

Comment: You can already see how many have been "removed" today by going to the stats page for the queue. Why would we show that on the main page?

Comment: @animuson The idea is to show a smaller number on the review page, to make people less scared of diving into the queue, and making them feel like they can actually make a difference.

Comment: Well, ideally I'd just find the link and consider it close enough to just be a duplicate.  In short, I personally don't see it as helping, not that I really think it would hurt anything either.  Based on my experiences, people don't dislike reviewing there because the queue is so large, the queue is large because people dislike reviewing there.

Comment: @Undo: So how does showing *two* numbers achieve that goal?

Comment: @animuson Showing the new number doesn't seem to be the meat of the suggestion; the main suggestion is to not show the actual count; showing this instead is more of just something to fill the space.

Comment: This has the key advantage over some of the other suggestions of; not being a lie

Comment: To me it shows 85.1k *questions*. Reviews needed is somewhat larger. The questions in over questions out seems to be around 250 per day.

Comment: Of all the suggestions I've seen, this is not among the worst, but I do think it's the one that will have the least impact. But who knows, we can always just try it for a while.